# ping from a jupyter notebook (or python in general)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ping

I would like to do something like (Windows 7/10 underneath)

```
for i in range (1,254):
    ! ping -n 1 192.168.2.+str(i)
```

Reason behind: want to quickly scan my WLAN to see where responding IP addresses are (finding a repeater).

Is there a python package allowing for this directly and how do I pass
a parameter to the bang command in the above (pseudo-) example?

OK, I found this working, but not elegant:

```
import os
for i in range (1,100):
    n= "192.168.2."+str(i)
    ! ping -n 1 $n
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you essentially answered the question yourself. You don't need to cast to string:

```
for i in range (1, 100):
    ! ping -n 1 192.168.2.$i
```

And for future reference, you can execute python code in the magic `!` command using curly braces. This is equivalent to the above:

```
for i in range (1, 100):
    ! ping -n 1 192.168.2.{i}

for i in range (1, 100):
    ! ping -n 1 192.168.2.{str(i)}
```

And obiously you can also do stuff like e.g.:

```
for i in range (1, 8):
    ! ping -n 1 192.168.2.{pow(2, i) - 1}
```